# Ударение и части речи

Tags: орфоэпия, части-речи

В каком слове при ударении на другой слог меняется не только значение, но и часть речи?
**Жаркое, кружки, стрелки.**

Answer (score 1):

Кру́жка — **кру́жки**; кружо́к — **кружки́** (сущ.).
Стре́лка — **стре́лки**; стрело́к — **стрелки́** (сущ.).

**Жарко́е** — мясное блюдо (**существительное**, неодушевлённое, средний род).
*Такое жарко́е с черносливом готовит только моя мама* (А. Маринина).

**Жа́ркое** — жа́ркое солнце, жа́ркое лето, жа́ркое объятие (**прилагательное**, качественное, средний род).

Искомая группа: жарко́е (сущ.) — жа́ркое (прил.).

Comment: А как же политика сайта?

Comment: Эх-эх, дилемма... Зато красиво и правильно.

Comment: Бьёте наповал старика. По всему Вы молоды и всё ещё впереди.